# Python String split by specific pattern with Indices

Tags: python, split, tokenize, python-re

I'm trying to split sentences from different characters, where each word has its own tag, and store with indices, and names can be Mike or Steve with different lengths. Content can be multiple languages like Chinese or Japanese, etc.

```
content = "A:Hello.B:How are you?A:I'm fine."
```

which I want to be like:

```
[0]A:Hello.       , 0:7
[1]B:How are you? , 8:21
[2]A:I'm fine.    ,22:33
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) as follow:

```py
import re
s = "A:Hello.B:How are you?A:I'm fine."
t = re.split(r'[.?]', s)
print(t)
```

that gives

```
['A:Hello', 'B:How are you', "A:I'm fine", '']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.finditer` for the task:

```
import re

content = "A:Hello.B:How are you?A:I'm fine."

for idx, i in enumerate(re.finditer(r'(.*?[.?])(?=[A-Z]|\Z)', content)):
    print('[{}]{:<20}, {}:{}'.format(idx, i.group(1), i.start(), i.end()-1))
```

Prints:

```
[0]A:Hello.            , 0:7
[1]B:How are you?      , 8:21
[2]A:I'm fine.         , 22:32
```

Comment: Much better than mine!